# Drop-down validation list created dynamically

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In range A1 I have a drop-down validation list. Based on the user's selection from that list I would like to dynamically create a new drop-down validation list in range C1.
For instance, in A1 the list contains:

A

B

C

So if the user selects A from the list, the new list in C1 contains:

1) Annoying Orange

2) Angry Birds

3) Arbitrary Sample

If the user selects B, the new list contains:

1) Bloated Code

2) Better Left Unsaid

3) Bad Attempt

etc

Easy enough to do using VBA. But in GAS.... I have absolutely *no idea* of how to even start :/

Answer (score 5):

The Apps Script API for data validation was just released:
http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/08/answering-another-top-request-data.html

Answer (score 3):

You could follow the example in the accepted answer to [Google spreadsheet Script Create Data Validation in certain range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790803/google-spreadsheet-script-create-data-validation-in-certain-range).

... up until last week, it would have worked. Unfortunately, the [Data Validation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation) class and related Range methods `getDataValidation()` and `setDataValidation()` have disappeared.

Your only avenue at this point is to visit [Issue 2958](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2958) and star it, so you receive updates if & when the API is refreshed.

Comment: The validations have been added. The ticket Issue 2958 has been closed.