# Insert Data Validation using Google Apps Script

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-apps-script, validation

I'm trying to insert an in cell dropdown menu (Data > Validation > List of Items) in a Gsheet using Google Apps Script. I want to do this because every time I use the spreadsheet the 'list of items' will change slightly and I don't wanna have to go to "Data > Validation > List of Items" every time I open the spreadsheet.

I'm aware that "Data > Validation > List from a Range" exists but I'd rather not use it.

Comment: Not possible at the moment.

Comment: Why not use list from a range?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An Apps Script API for data validation was just released:
http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/08/answering-another-top-request-data.html

Related references:

- [Drop-down validation list created dynamically (google apps script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515902/drop-down-validation-list-created-dynamically-google-apps-script)
- https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2958
- https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=219