# Data Validation in code (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, validation

I have the following script that runs on the 'onEdit' trigger (that part is working just fine)

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(sheet.getName() == "Plan" && myRange.getColumn() == 2 && myRange.getRow() > 3){
    var option = new Array();
    option[0]="0";
    option[1]="1";
    option[2]="2";
    var dv = sheet.getRange(myRange.getRow(),myRange.getColumn() + 1).getValidation();
    dv.setAllowInvalidData(false);
    dv.setHelpText("Some help text here");
    dv.setCriteria(SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.ITEM_IN_LIST,true,option );
    sheet.getRange(myRange.getRow(),myRange.getColumn() + 1) .setValidation(dv); 
  }
}
```

That most of the code came from the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790803/google-spreadsheet-script-create-data-validation-in-certain-range) question. Problem is that the

```
dv.setCriteria(SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.ITEM_IN_LIST,true,option );
```

line of code doesn't work, the compiler won't even let me save it. In my looking around as to why, it seems Google has changed how it is handled, and taken their docs about it offline. Can anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep it seems something changed...

try that:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(sheet.getName() == "Plan" && myRange.getColumn() == 2 && myRange.getRow() > 3){
    var option = new Array();
    option[0]="0";
    option[1]="1";
    option[2]="2";
    //    var dv = sheet.getRange(myRange.getRow(),myRange.getColumn() + 1).getValidation();
    var dv = sheet.getRange(myRange.getRow(),myRange.getColumn() + 1).getDataValidation();
    var dv = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();
    //    dv.setAllowInvalidData(false);
    dv.setAllowInvalid(false);  
    dv.setHelpText("Some help text here");
    dv.requireValueInList(option, true);
//    dv.setCriteria(SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.ITEM_IN_LIST,true,option );
//    sheet.getRange(myRange.getRow(),myRange.getColumn() + 1).setValidation(dv); 
    sheet.getRange(myRange.getRow(),myRange.getColumn() + 1).setDataValidation(dv.build()); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Did you just know that off the top of your head, or find some docs on somewhere that I didn't see? Thanks!

Comment: well I already done something like that, but I didn't really remembered how i did it, so I put your code in a GAS editor and played a little bit with the autocompletion :D